# Tkinter window opens from command line but not IDE

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this script from Windows PowerShell, the tkinter window will open. However, when I run the script from an IDE (Wing IDE 101 6.0) the script will run and return without any errors or windows popping up. How can I get the tkinter window to pop up without having to use powershell?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class MyGame:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Stock Market Game')

        self.startGameButton = tk.Button(master, text="Start New Game", command = self.startNewGame)
        self.startGameButton.pack()

        cWidth = 600
        cHeight = 400
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width = cWidth, height = cHeight)
        self.canvas.create_line(0, cHeight * 1/3, cWidth, cHeight * 1/3)   # coordinates of start and end
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind("Start New Game", self.startNewGame)        

    def startNewGame(self):
        pass


root = Tk()
gui = MyGame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's pretty old, but might be worth a shot: See section [6.20 Non-Python Mainloop Environments](http://wingide.com/psupport/wingide-1.1/node7.html#SECTION007200000000000000000) in this Version 1.1.10 Wing IDE Reference Manual.

Comment: The code works in my Wing Personal 6.0.10.